# Increment numbers in a Pandas column, based on existing highest value

Tags: python, pandas

I'm trying to concat two dataframes.  dfA has incremental numbers in column 1, dfB does not.  Starting from highest value in dfA, I would like to increment the numbers in the rows from dfB when they are concatenated in dfC.  So it should be:

dfA:

| Column 1 | Column 2 |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | John |
| 2 | Peter |

dfB:

| Column 1 | Column 2 |
| --- | --- |
|  | Sara |
|  | Paul |

dfC (concat of dfA and dfB):

| Column 1 | Column 2 |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | John |
| 2 | Peter |
| 3 | Sara |
| 4 | Paul |

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks all, appreciate your help as it gave me the pieces I needed to make this work!  I just kept it super simple:

```
dfB['Column1'] = dfA['Column1'].max() + dfB.index + 1
dfC = pd.concat([dfA,dfB])
```

Answer (score 0):

You could modify `dfB` like this -

```
dfB['Column 1'] = pd.Series(list(range(dfA['Column 1'].max(), dfA['Column 1'].max() + len(dfB.index))))
```

Then you could simply concatenate `dfA` and the updated version of `dfB`.

Answer (score 0):

You can first assign values starting from the next to last value of dfA's Column1 to Column1 of dfB and then concat :

```
dfB['Column1'] = pd.Series(list(range(1+dfA['Column1'].iloc[-1],len(dfB)+len(dfA)))
dfC = pd.concat([dfA,dfB])
```

Answer (score 0):

You can take the highest value of dfA's Column 1, then replace dfB's Column 1 values. Just create a sequence from the highest value (from dfA) and from there using range() and replace, for example:

```
# Recreating data for example
dfA = {'Column 1': [1, 2], 'Column 2': ['John', 'Peter']}
dfA = pd.DataFrame(data=dfA)
dfB = {'Column 1': [0, 0], 'Column 2': ['John', 'Peter']}
dfB = pd.DataFrame(data=dfB)

# Specifying the range and replacing the values in Column 1
start = len(dfB['Column 1']) + 1
stop = start + dfA['Column 1'].max()
dfB['Column 1'] = range(start, stop)

# Concatenate both df
dfC = pd.concat([dfA, dfB], axis=0)
```

Output should be the following:

```
Column 1    Column 2
    1         John
    2         Peter
    3         John
    4         Peter
```